# Searching for a Library for Detecting Comparatives and Superlatives in Natural Language

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-analysis, pos-tagger

I'm analyzing natural language texts in java and am currently looking for a library that enables to detect comparatives and superlatives (e.g. "better", "fastest",...) in German language.

I used the POS Tagger of the Stanford NLP, which worked fine for English, but is less detailed in German (detects only adjectives, but no morphological features, as far as I tried).

Does anyone know such a library/model (also non-java-libraries etc.)?

Thanks a lot!
Henning

Answer (score 0):

Try using **GATE(General Architecture for Text Engineering).** It is a **open-source framework** for Natural Language Processing(NLP) and text analytics. It support multiple languages. As far as I know, it does **support German language**. Check it out.

Some useful links :

- http://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html
- http://gate.ac.uk/news.html

Comment: I have used it to certain extent but not very thoroughly.